# auto mapper Inner Exception IEnumerable<Office>to List<ListOfficeModel>

Tags: c#, automapper

My AutoMapper throws an exception on var result line.  I don't know what I am missing, what the cause of this exceptions is

stack output

> AutoMapper.AutoMapperMappingException: Error mapping types.
>
> Mapping types: IEnumerable`1 -> List`1
>   System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[[RoomBooking.Domain.Office,
>   RoomBooking.Domain, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null]] ->
>   System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[RoomBooking.Application.Couties.Queries.ListOfficeModel,
>   RoomBooking.Application, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null]] ---> AutoMapper.AutoMapperMappingException:
>   Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping.
>
> Mapping types: Office -> ListOfficeModel RoomBooking.Domain.Office ->
>   RoomBooking.Application.Couties.Queries.ListOfficeModel    at
>   lambda_method(Closure , Office , ListOfficeModel , ResolutionContext )
>   at AutoMapper.ResolutionContext.Map[TSource,TDestination](TSource
>   source, TDestination destination)    at lambda_method(Closure ,
>   IEnumerable`1 , List`1 , ResolutionContext )    --- End of inner
>   exception stack trace ---    at lambda_method(Closure , IEnumerable`1
>   , List`1 , ResolutionContext )    at
>   AutoMapper.Mapper.AutoMapper.IMapper.Map[TSource,TDestination](TSource
>   source)    at
>   RoomBooking.Application.Couties.Queries.GetOfficesListQuery.Execute()
>   in
>   D:\TFS\Book-a-Room\src\RoomBooking\RoomBooking.Application\Offices\Queries\GetOfficesListQuery.cs:line
>   21    at RoomBooking.Presentation.Controllers.OfficeController.Get()
>   in
>   D:\TFS\Book-a-Room\src\RoomBooking\RoomBooking.Presentation\Controllers\OfficeController.cs:line
>   18    at lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object[] )    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.d__27.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.d__25.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContext
>   context)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State&
>   next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.d__22.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContext
>   context)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State&
>   next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.d__20.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.RouterMiddleware.d__4.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session.SessionMiddleware.d__9.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session.SessionMiddleware.d__9.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.BrowserLinkMiddleware.d__7.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.d__7.MoveNext()

```
public class ListOfficeModel
{
    public long RecordId { get; set; }

    public long OfficeId { get; set; }
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }
    public int? DiplayOrder { get; set; }

}

public class Office 
{
    [Key]
    public long RecordId { get; set; }

    public long OfficeId { get; set; }
    public string  DisplayName { get; set; }
    public int? DiplayOrder { get; set; }
    public long? CountyId { get; set; }
    public bool? Deleted { get; set; }
    public bool? IsBranch { get; set; }
}

        public List<ListOfficeModel> Execute()
        {
            var offices = this.databaseService.SelectOfficesforList();

            Mapper.Initialize(cfg => {
                cfg.CreateMap<Office, ListOfficeModel>();
            });
//the exception happen here 
            var result = Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<Office>, List<ListOfficeModel>>(offices);
            return result;
        }
```

Comment: can you add the whole error message?

Comment: I added error message

Comment: how are you injecting the mapper on your controllers?

Comment: usually automapper with the error has another output on the message like this: At the time of the exception, the container was: (HERE it says what was automapper trying to resolve at that time), please paste that part

Comment: @Zinov the stack output

Comment: is that exception.message?

Comment: Yes, this is  exception.message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code sample runs fine on a clean install of AutoMapper 6.0.2.

Something which stands out as incorrect is that you are initialising your mapper in your Execute method.  You should initialise Mapper *once* and only once per application - in your application startup.  Move the Mapper.Initialize section there and see if it works.

Comment: I  include AggregateRoot class do you think it is the cause of the problem?